# How to find min/max values in columns of csv files into JSON like format in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to take in a few csv files, each of which would looks like this:

```
                column1     column2        column3       
18/05/16 11:19  143501      148686          40644           
18/05/16 11:34  144070      144710          79585           
18/05/16 11:49  134070      144713          79588           
18/05/16 12:03  144070      144716          80591           
18/05/16 12:13  144070      144733          79608           
18/05/16 12:23  154790      144733          79608           
18/05/16 12:19  144070      125753          79628           
18/05/16 12:34  144070      144757          79632
```

I want to obtain the max and min value for each column in each csv file (excluding the date/time column)
and put the data into a structure something like this:

```
{
    'csvfile1' :[{

        "column1": [{
            "max": "154790"
            "min": "134070"
            }],
        "column2": [{
            "max": "148686"
            "min": "125753"
            }],
        "column3": [{
            "max": "80591"
            "min": "40644"
            }]
        }],
    'csvfile2' :[{
        <same type of information here>
    }],
    'csvfile3' :[{
        <same type of information here>
    }]
}
```

This is my script so far:

```
max_min_data={}
for name in csvfile_names:
    f = open(name+'.csv', "r")

    #Only want to check columns 1 to 3 not the date/time
    for number in range(1,3):
        f.seek(0)
        column_names = next(f) next(f) # Skip header
        max_value = max(int(row[number]) for row in csv.reader(f))
        min_value = min(int(row[number]) for row in csv.reader(f))

        max_min_data[name]=[column_names[number]]
        max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]=['max','min']
        max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['max']=max_value
        max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['min']=min_value

        print "MAX:"
        print '\t\t'+str(max_value)
        print "MIN:"
        print '\t\t'+str(min_value)
```

Comment: Show the wrong output

Comment: ^ I think that meant "show the output you get that you don't want."

Comment: Make sure `row[number]` is a number (integer or float) and not a string.

Comment: comparing strings doesn't do the same thing as comparing numbers, it checks in terms of the first character then second and so on, so `max('123', '23') -> '23'` since `'2'` is greater then `'1'`

Comment: `max(int(row[number]) for row in csv.reader(f))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare two python strings that contain numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062973/compare-two-python-strings-that-contain-numbers)

Comment: @ozgur Thank you that solved the max issue but what would be the best method to put that data into the format I have above?

Comment: Can you show us the code that converts the given csv to the above dictionary?

Comment: @ozgur I have updated my code above to include the code that converts the given csv to the above dictionary

Comment: @Catherine Define "best method"? Fastest, cleanest, least number of lines, no dependencies?

Comment: @oystein My current method as shown in my code isn't working, by "best" I meant "cleanest" or "most pythonic way" of creating the dictionary structure described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `pandas` is allowed, this is very simple. You need to load the csv into a dataframe, use the `describe` method, select only the 'min' and 'max' rows, and then create a JSON object from the dataframe. The important thing here is that *pandas already provides all of that functionality*.

Load your csv file as a dataframe with `pandas.read_csv`. Assuming you have it as a dataframe `df` like this:

```
                column1  column2  column3
18/05/16 11:19   143501   148686    40644
         11:34   144070   144710    79585
         11:49   134070   144713    79588
         12:03   144070   144716    80591
         12:13   144070   144733    79608
         12:23   154790   144733    79608
         12:19   144070   125753    79628
         12:34   144070   144757    79632
```

Then you use `desc = df.describe()` to generate a dataframe `desc` like:

```
            column1        column2       column3
count       8.000000       8.000000      8.000000
mean   144088.875000  142850.125000  74860.500000
std      5545.130565    7045.836226  13829.840615
min    134070.000000  125753.000000  40644.000000
25%    143927.750000  144712.250000  79587.250000
50%    144070.000000  144724.500000  79608.000000
75%    144070.000000  144739.000000  79629.000000
max    154790.000000  148686.000000  80591.000000
```

If you subset the rows of the dataframe above with `desc.loc[['min','max']]`, you get:

```
      column1  column2  column3
min   134070   125753    40644
max   154790   148686    80591
```

Then, you can just get it as a JSON object with a call to `to_json`, like `desc.loc[['min','max']].to_json()` which can either save directly to a file or generate a string (take a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)).

From there, composing multiple such processes and writing to file should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this :

```
max_value = max(int(row[number]) for row in csv.reader(f))
```

Indeed, when you parse the CSV file, the reader assumes these values are strings, you are therefore comparing them by string comparison, and not getting the actual max value.