# How to compare Twitter Ids in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm working with twitter ids which are strings because they are so huge.

Twitter's api has a "Since_id" and I want to search tweets since the earliest tweet in a list.

For example:

```
tweet_ids = [u'1003659997241401843', u'1003659997241401234234', u'100365999724140136236'] # etc
since_id = min(tweet_ids)
```

So far `min(tweet_ids)` works but I want to understand why it works because I want to know if it is just by chance that it worked on the few samples I gave it, or if it is guaranteed to always work.

**Edit: To clarify I need to get the lowest tweet id. How do I get the lowest tweet id if they are strings that are > 2^32-1 and therefore can't be represented as integers in python 2.7 on a 32 bit machine.**

I am using python 2.7 if that matters

Comment: If all strings are guaranteed to be the same length, it _might_ be slightly faster to do `min(tweet_ids)` instead of `min(tweet_ids, key=int)`. But the speed gain is unlikely to matter, and you'd need some kind of comment explaining why it's safe to compare them as strings or your code will look suspicious to any reader (including you in a few months), so I'd go with the conversion to `int`.

Comment: *I'm working with twitter ids which are strings because they are so huge* This is a non-problem in Python, whose ints are not limited to machine words. Represent the ids as ints, and your problems will go away.

Comment: In Python 2.7, you might want to use `key=long` instead of `key=int`. Python 2.x had two different integer types; `int` is as big as a C `long` (usually 32 bits), while `long` is a list of digits that can go as long as you have memory for. In 2.7, `int` values are automatically promoted to `long` when necessary, but if you care more about clarity than 3.x portability, I think it makes sense to be explicit here.

Comment: Meanwhile, the reason the Twitter API sends these numbers as strings is a limitation of JSON. JSON allows all numbers to be represented by a `float64`. If you stick a 70-bit integer in a `float64`, you lose the rightmost few digits, which is obviously not acceptable. So they pass them as strings, which you can convert to `long` in Python 2.x, `int` in Python 3.x, `BigInt` in Scala, or whatever type your language offers that JSON doesn't.

Comment: @abarnert I don't think this question is a duplicate, since it involves finding better alternatives to string comparison. I provided an alternative approach to his question which involves conversion to an int and back.

Comment: It's a little silly that XY questions like this one get marked as duplicates. Even before the edits, you could see that the problem of the OP was not how strings are compared.. Anyways, abernert's comments above are the (best IMHO) answer to the question.

Comment: There are definitely other questions on SO about ints being compared lexicographically and what to do about it, so rather than un-dup this, we should just find the best one and retarget it.

Comment: I suppose the ideal duplicate question would be one that covered the use of `key` as well as converting all of the numbers. Which means there may not be a single ideal dup, but we can always add two (or more) targets.

Comment: There are multiple questions on natural sorting, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062973/compare-two-python-strings-that-contain-numbers), but that's overkill here (as well as not obviously related), so it's definitely not the right dup; just something to get on the Linked Questions list…

Comment: There's still a side question on `int` vs. `long` in Python 2.x, and when they get auto-converted in later 2.x, and so on. If you're still confused by that, there's probably an existing question, but if you can't find one, ask and… someone else can find the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types), it implies that all Strings, including your case where the strings are large sequences of digits, are compared *lexicographically*.

- The "lesser integer" string `2` is less than then "greater integer" string `100` in this case.
- Negative integers sorted lexicographically are "greater" than positive integers. `"-1"` is greater than `"99"` when compared this way because the minus hyphen is lexicographically greater than all digits.
- Equal integers `"2"` and `"02"` aren't necessarily equal in terms of string comparison. `"02"` is less than `"2"` string-wise because of the leading zero.

It is better to convert the str into a long int, and then compare it. As in

- `tweet_ids = [long('1003659997241401843'), long('1003659997241401234234'), long('100365999724140136236')]`
- `since_id = min(tweet_ids)`

Since JSON does not allow 70-bit long ints, convert the smallest int back into a str. Replace the `since_id` line with

- `since_id = min(tweet_ids, key=int)`

Comment: I thought twitter uses strings because the numbers are so large they can't be represented as ints?

Comment: They can be represented as ints. Large ints and longs with arbitrary precision. Sort them as ints.

Comment: I disagree. I'm using python 2.7 and on google app engine. My guess is app engine is still 32 bit so that would mean my largest int would 4.3 billion. These tweet ids are much larger than 4 billion

Comment: compare for how Python handles int: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints

Comment: @TerenceChow They're too large to be represented as integers _in JSON_. That's because JSON explicitly documents that numbers are to be treated as `float64` values, and if you store a 70-bit integer in a `float64` value, you lose the last few digits. They're not too large to be represented as integers _in Python_, because Python represents integers as a list of (30-bit) digits, so you can hold as big a number as you want (until you run out of memory).

Comment: @abamert Sorry about that. Is there any way to improve my answer? One suggestion is to convert the least int *back* into a string. Is it recommended that this question is to be de-duped since there is a *better* alternative to just comparing strings?

Comment: @abarnert ahhh didn't know that! thank youu

Comment: @TerenceChow Do you want to consider converting the smallest int to a str?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous I don't think the question should be deduped. But meanwhile, your answer could be improved in a few ways. First, if the tweet IDs are going to be used as strings, just use `min(tweet_ids, key=int)` instead of converting them all and then converting back. Second, as I explained in a comment, if this code isn't meant to be portable to 3.x, I'd use `long` explicitly rather than `int`. Also, it's 70 bits, not digits.

Comment: @abarnert Done. Thanks for suggesting me a better answer. Since there may be a subtle difference in comparing generic strings and how the asker intended to compare these int-strings, is it better to suggest this question to leave it as a dupe, to retarget the dupe?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous As I said in a comment on the question, I think it's better to retarget the dup… as soon as someone can find a good duplicate. There's nothing relevant in https://sopython.com/canon and searching is always a pain, but I'm looking…

Answer (score 0):

Python will compare these strings exactly as it compares any other strings; that is, it will compare them lexicographically.

Thus, it will put `12` before `2`, which may be undesirable for you.

Here's a function that will compute the numerical minimum of strings representing integers for you.

```
# A is an iterable of strings representing integers.
def numerical_min(A):
    cur_min = A[0]
    for x in A[1:]:
        if len(x) < len(cur_min):
            cur_min = x
            continue
        if len(x) > len(cur_min):
            continue
        for m,n in zip(x, cur_min):
            if int(m) < int(n):
                cur_min = x
                break
    return cur_min
```

Comment: What's the best way to compare these in this case?

Comment: @TerenceChow, I've added a solution which is independent of how large your integers represented as strings are.